# What is the red arrow to the left of the line numbers on Atom?

Tags: atom-editor

What does the red arrow --seen between lines 95 and 96 in the screenshot below-- mean on GitHub's Atom editor?

Thanks!

[image: Screenshot of Atom with the red arrow]

Comment: Git gutter line delete?

Answer (score 54, accepted):

If your currently open project is using Git as a revisioning system, the arrow in the gutter means that you deleted one or more lines at this location in the file.

If you commit (or roll back) your changes, the arrow is going to disappear.

Running a "git diff" on your file should show that you deleted some content between lines 95 and 96.

Depending on the theme you're using in Atom, the arrow's color might be different from the one in the screenshot.

Comment: Is there a toggle to turn this feature off?